# Does shaking an atom produce photons?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photon-emission

I have a vague recollection of a description of the relationship between matter and light.  It went something along the lines of this:  "Grab hold of `a thing` and shake it up and down."  (More on the `thing` below.)  "This will emit electromagnetic radiation.  The faster you shake it, the higher the frequency of the radiation.  E.g., if you could shake it 600,000,000,000 times per second then … `frequency = c / wavelength` … the radiation would have a wavelength of 400nm, which is a frequency we perceive as green."  Continuing this scenario, "The harder you shake it the more radiation it emits.  I.e., shake it twice as hard and it will emit twice(?) as many photons."

My general question is whether this is in any literal sense true?

If so, for what `things` is it true?  Any atom?  Any collection of atoms?  (E.g., this is true of a solid rod of any material?)  Atoms regardless of their ionization state?  Regardless of their material "state" (i.e., including plasma or condensates)?

Comment: Yes, for example - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_(radio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you to produce radiation in the form of photons by shaking a *thing*, that *thing* has to be charged. So for example, an electron vibrating will produce radiation with amplitude proportional to the amplitude of the vibration and frequency equal to that of said vibration.

If the *thing* is not charged, then it doesn't produce any electromagnetic field, and then if you shake it, no photons are emitted.

Also, number of photons is proportional to the intensity, and intensity is proportional to the amplitude of the field squared. That means that if you increase the amplitude of the vibration of the electron, you will produce 4 times as many photons.

Finally, to produce a constant stream of photons notice that you need to give a constant amount of energy to the particle you are shaking, so if you just make it wiggle a little, it will eventually lose all its vibrational energy in the form of photons and stop moving.

And to answer the question in the title, shaking an uncharged atom does not produce anything if it stays uncharged all the way through. But if the atom is ionized in any way, it will produce some.

Comment: So this is true of any *thing* that is charged.  The means an electron, or an ion – including a proton (ionized H), right?  Does it also mean, on a larger scale, a solid rod (or other mass of molecules) with a net static charge?

Comment: Yeah sure, assuming the charge remains constant it would produce electromagnetic radiation. Anything that produces en electromagnetic field (a charge for example) will do that when you move it.