# What causes the direction of a photon?

Tags: electromagnetism, photons, quantum-electrodynamics

I wondered if protons or any charged particle could generate photons and I found this wonderful answer that says yes: [Does shaking an atom produce photons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/538441/)

The issue now is that the more I thought about it the more I became confused and here is why. If any shaking charged thing can make a photon, well, which way does the photon choose to go?

I don't have a clear understanding of photons so maybe that's the problem, so to better answer me I'll give my understanding: Photons are packets of energy that represent an oscillating electric and magnetic fields. Please correct me on that if I'm wrong, I'm mostly using the visual model of a photon when I describe it. How does a photon decide in which direction it moves? Is it just completely random?

Comment: This problem is hidden quite deeply in quantum texts. Consider a system that is spherically symmetric. Then, the photon coming out of the decay is also going to be spherically symmetric. However, upon detection, it will have to have a specific direction, namely the direction from the atom to the detector. This is related to the measurement problem, the collapse of the wavefunction from spherically symmetric to not spherically symmetric.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent   "Then, the photon coming out of the decay is also going to be spherically symmetric. " This is not correct for individual photons. The **distribution** of photons will be spherically symmetric, Indivdiual photon direction will depend on the quantum mechanical calculations.https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Simon-Vallieres/publication/317548664/figure/fig4/AS:613998298935296@1523400010117/Schematic-of-an-atomic-Compton-scattering-event.png  . from https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Schematic-of-an-atomic-Compton-scattering-event_fig4_317548664

Comment: @annav what you are saying is what I said at the back.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent seems like a good answer, you may write it down...

Answer (score 0):

A photon is emitted during a jump between to energy level states.

The photon carries away a unit of spin $\hbar$. The atom has to loose a unit $\hbar$ of total angular momentum and its energy.

In the simplest cases jumps can occure in three ways, flip of nuclear spin, flip of electron spin or reduction or addition  by one unit $\hbar$ to the orbital momentum component in the direction of the photons  momentum vector, that is its spin axis, too.

In any case, the operator disturbing the system and causing the jump is the external electric field of the outgoing photon at the origin.

Because its wavelength is typically some 137 times longer than the size of the atom, only the linear approximation of the dipol field at the origin over the extension of the bound states enters the probability integral by its matrix element between the two states.

This is the operator of the dipol moment $\psi_1^* \vec x \psi_2$ between the higher energy prepared state and the final state after emission.

This dipolmoment is never spherical but has a preferred antenna axis, if the total angular momentum has a definite direction (eg in a small magnetic field fro alignment) as pure state angular momentum state series.

If the atom state is a mixed state over all directions, finally, the statistical directions of pure states mix uniformLy over the unit sphere. As always, a single photon event can occur at any direction. Only the random pattern of absorbed photons of repeated, statistically independent, emission events, absorbed on the sphere at infinity, is the topic of the quantum mechanical description.

All this belongs to the not so easy to describe science of spectroscopy, selection rules (and superselection rules) and spectral intensity distributions.

The triumph of Schrödinger, Heisenberg, Born, Pauli, Dirac was to be able to compress ten volumes of spectroscopic data into a single 1-line equation and to find an explanation of any feature by a careful mathematical analysis.

The standard situation in the H-atom in the first exited level with angular momentum $\hbar$ is the jump to the spherical ground state with $\psi_1 =  \cos \theta e^{-r/r_1}$ and $\psi_0 = e^{-r/r_0}$. This yields maximal intensity for dipol emission with $z$-axis.  The distribution over the angular coordinate $\phi$ is uniform over the circle.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify matters, I'll consider the case of a single charged particle being "shaken" to produce EM radiation.  If we now consider the radiation in terms of photons, then the question is, in which direction does the photon propagate?

We may say it propagates in all directions and therefore, the state of the photon is a superposition of fixed momentum states, with coefficients given by the angular distribution for dipole radiation.  (The direction of the "shaking" defines the orientation of the dipole.)

If we assume that we shake the charge with just enough energy, as related to the frequency of the shaking, to produce only one photon, then we have a probability distribution to measure this photon along a given direction that corresponds to angular distribution for dipole radiation.

It begs the question that photons are particles with fixed propagation directions.  Such a view may be misleading.  A better way to think of it is as a wave function that has the properties of the dipole radiation.  The single photon detection at a given location is then imposed by the detection process, with a probability depending on the properties of the radiated wave function.  So, it is not necessary for us to assume that photons are particles propagating in specific directions.